# Online Judge:Array Normalization,I don't know why I am wrong

Tags: c++

Description:
For an array consists of several non-negative int,array nomalization means every element will be divides by the sum of the array.Presuming that the array consists of at least one element,and the sum of elements won't be beyond the max of int.

Input:
several non-negative int

Output:
the result of normalization.

Sample Input
1 2 3 4

Sample Output
0.10 0.20 0.30 0.40

I think it's an easy problem,but the Accept Rate is only 12/1352.This is my code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,t=0,sum=0;
    vector<int> arr;
    while(cin>>a)
    {
        arr.push_back(a);
        t++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        sum+=arr[i];
    if(sum)
    {
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<setprecision(2)<<1.0*arr[0]/sum;
        for(int i=1;i<t;i++)
        {
            cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<setprecision(2)<<" "<<1.0*arr[i]/sum;
        }
    }else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            if(i==0)
                cout<<"0.00";
            else
                cout<<" 0.00";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### The output is the same to the sample output.But I get a wrong answer 75%,I don't know what tips I have not considered.

I figure it out,it's not a good problem,0/0 should output 1

Comment: What does `the Accept Rate is only 12/1352` mean?

Comment: @goodvibration It means the OP is using some online programming test software which provided 1352 mystery test cases for which the OP's solution passed just 12.

Comment: Also, your code looks a lot more cumbersome than it should be. Everything split into several cases, which seem to be pretty redundant.

Comment: @goodvibration Don't be rude. 1352/1352 is a pass by definition, no matter your opinion of the subjective quality of the submission.

Comment: I can't immediately see why this would fail almost all testcases. Precedence is right, precision is right, types are right (or at least sufficient given the problem constraints)

Comment: It could be that the problem is underspecified in terms of the significant figures they want output. That's the problem with "challenges" like this.

Comment: Usually, a newline is added to the output stream at the end of a line. Could you please post the *exact* description of the required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you are right, it is an easy problem. Your output statement

```
cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)<<setprecision(2)<<" "<<1.0*arr[i]/sum;
```

formats the output with

- setiosflags(ios::fixed)
- setprecision(2)

Meaning, you are showing exactly 2 digits for the fraction. And everytime, when

> (1.0*arr[i] / sum) < 0.01

The result will be shown as exactly 0.00

Hope this helps